# Compiling VXL in Mac OS 10.8.2, X11/Xlib.h not found

Tags: c++, cmake, x11, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to install the VXL, when I typed in "make -j1", I got this

```
[ 10%] Building C object v3p/netlib/examples/CMakeFiles/netlib_showme.dir/showme.o
/Users/viviantung/downloads/vxl-1.17.0/v3p/netlib/examples/showme.c:106:10: fatal error: 
  'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [v3p/netlib/examples/CMakeFiles/netlib_showme.dir/showme.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [v3p/netlib/examples/CMakeFiles/netlib_showme.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What should I do? I already have XQuartz installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

X11 header files are located under `/usr/X11R6/include` directory. What you need to do is ask the compiler to search there by using `-isystem /usr/X11R6/include` command line option. Or, if you are using CMake, use `include_directories("/usr/X11R6/include")`.

Comment: i'm using CMake. Can you be a little bit more specific on what should i really put in the command line. What i typed was just "make", so I don't know when should put "-isystem /usr/X11R6/include" or "include_directories("/usr/X11R6/include")". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1978333: `include_directories("/usr/X11R6/include")` goes into your Cmake file. Then you run cmake, then run make. Use Google or something, like "How to add include path to Cmake" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. download `vxl-1.14.0`
2. create a folder named `vxl`, extract the `vxl-1.14.0.zip` in `vxl`, also create a folder named `bin` under `vxl` folder.
3. make sure you installed `cmake` and `xquartz`.
4. open terminal, cd in the path of bin folder you created and typed `ccmake /User/..../vxl/vxl-1.14.0`  press `c` until you can press `g` to generate.
   then press `g`, and press `q` to quit.
5. under bin folder typed `make -j2 -k`

hope you can build it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way to solve this problem if all else fails is to define CXXFLAGS or CFLAGS in your environment.

Add

```
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/X11/include"
```

or

```
export CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/X11/include"
```

depending on c or c++ compiler into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile and then rerun.